# OPL ILOG CPLEX optimization

Tags: cplex, ilog, opl

Three decision variables M, O and Z,

```
forall (k in 1..Cells, i in 1..nbMachines, j in 1..nbComps)
{(U[k][i][j] == 1) && ( A[k][i] <= -1 +((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52*5))
=> M[k][i][j]==1 ;  } 

forall (k in 1..Cells, i in 1..nbMachines, j in 1..nbComps)
{(V[k][i][j] == 1) && (A[k][i] >=  -1 + ((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52*5)) 
=> Z[k][i][j]==1 ;} 

forall (k in 1..Cells, i in 1..nbMachines, j in 1..nbComps)
{(V[k][i][j] == 1) && ( A[k][i]  >= -1 + ((D[k][j]*S[k][j])*52*5)) 
=> O[k][i][j]==1;}
```

- If U is 1, A is less than or equal to D*S*52*5, than M will be 1.
- If V is 1, A is more than  D*S*52*5, than Z will be 1.
- If V is 1, A is more than  D*S*52*5, than O will be 1.

In the run, M, Z and O are getting the same values.
The sum of M and Z as well as sum of M and O will be equal to U and V.
(U=V)
Please help me to write the correct expressions for finding out M, O and Z.
U and V are extracted in previous steps. A, D and S are input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the decision expression for a less wild guess by my side. I am assuming that all three lines are inside a `subject to {}` block. As your constraints 2 and 3 are literally the same (besides a missing space and a different letter O/Z) I guess Cplex comes up with the easiest solution by assigning the same values to all Decision variables.

Comment: The Objective function is Minimizing
sum (k in 1..Cells, i in 1..nbMachines, j in 1..nbComps) 
 (M[k][i][j] * A [k][i] 
+ Z[k][i][j] * I [k][j] * D[k][j] 
+ O[k][i][j] * S [k][j] * D [k][j]
+ W[k][i][j] * IA [k][j] * D[k][j]); The solution for decision variable W is obtained and the other variables M, Z and O have to find out.